# how to render a raised paper-button with reactjs?

Tags: polymer, reactjs

Here is the code that should render a "raised" paper-button:

All the code is in a script tag and renders a paper-button that is not RAISED (see screen shot). I can click and see the RIPPLE effect, seems perfect except the appearance.

UPDATE : 
for the moment the only way to get the correct rendering is by replacing

> ```
> <paper-button raised>test</paper-button>
> ```

BY

> ```
> <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<paper-button raised>test</paper-button>'}} />
> ```

ANY WORKAROUND avoiding this 'dangerous' way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <script src="bower_components/react/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/react/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>

    <script type="text/jsx">
        var ButtonT = React.createClass({

            render: function() {
                return (
                <div>
                    <paper-button raised="true">test</paper-button>
                </div>
                );
            }

        });
        React.render(
          <ButtonT />,
          document.getElementById('content')
        );

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Should the "raised" attribute be passed as a this.props...?

Comment: You can't pass custom attributes: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140.

Comment: possible duplicate of [True custom attributes (e.g. Microdata) in React](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648347/true-custom-attributes-e-g-microdata-in-react)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work in the current version of React.  Custom attribute support is an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140), though.  For now, I've found this [patch](https://gist.github.com/chinchang/a66fe3aedaf98b2433eb) works well.

Answer (score 0):

In JSX if you want a custom HTML attribute, you should prefix it with `data-`, it then will be resolved to actual name without prefix. See [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#custom-html-attributes);

Comment: No, it doesn't. It would be included as `data-raised` on the element. So unless the Polymer component could use that, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work and won't solve the question. :(