# How to add custom html attributes in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-component

There are different reasons behind it, but I wonder how to simply add custom attributes to an element in JSX?

Comment: May be one comment help someone, i found out React 16.7  ***doesnt rerenders*** and update the component's html attributes if you changed only them in a store (f.e. redux) and tied to component. This means the component has f.e.```aria-modal=true```, you push the changes (to false) to the store of **aria/data** attributes, but nothing else is changed (such as component's content or class or variables in there) as the result ReactJs will not update **aria/data**  attrs in that components. 
I've been messing around about whole day to realise that.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

### EDIT: Updated to reflect React 16

Custom attributes are supported natively in React 16. This means that adding a custom attribute to an element is now as simple as adding it to a `render` function, like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div custom-attribute="some-value" />
  );
}
```

For more:
https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#support-for-custom-dom-attributes
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html

---

### Previous answer (React 15 and earlier)

Custom attributes are currently not supported. See this open issue for more info:  https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140

As a workaround, you can do something like this in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.test);
  element.setAttribute('custom-attribute', 'some value');
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/peterjmag/kysymow0/ for a working example. (Inspired by syranide's suggestion in [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140#issuecomment-62527758).)

Comment: yeah, only this way I guess. [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/140#issuecomment-66755379) approach looks interesting though

Comment: i'm a total react n00b so sorry if this is a stupid question, but why not just add all the custom attributes in the ref callback? eg: ref={(thisSvgElement) => { thisSvgElement.setAttribute('xmlns:xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'); }}

Comment: @k7n4n5t3w4rt Yep, that should work too. Ref callbacks just didn't exist back when I wrote this answer.

Comment: This isn't entirely true. You can add a custom attribute by prepending it with `data-` or `aria-`. See [Luca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44569018/6131801) and/or the [React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html)

Comment: Why can you not do this on components so that the attr will be rendered on the first element in the render?

Answer (score 61):

You can add an attribute using ES6 spread operator, e.g.

```
let myAttr = {'data-attr': 'value'}
```

and in render method:

```
<MyComponent {...myAttr} />
```

Comment: Do you think this `let myAttr = {'custom-attr': 'value'}` would work?

Comment: It does work if you have a ES6 transpiler in your project

Comment: well, here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/andrx/pen/GNopRB?editors=0010). I don't see custom attribute there

Comment: @AndreyBorisko - The attributes will be effective as long as they are valid HTML5 attributes. I forked your pen and made changes: http://codepen.io/deveedutta/pen/ObqEQL
The button is clearly disabled.

Comment: @DDM `disabled` is not a custom attribute. It's a standard HTML attribute. Have I missed something in your example?

Comment: @AndreyBorisko - I intended to mention but missed, that invalid html attributes and custom attributes won't work as of now unless pre-fixed by `data-`.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading because the question is specific to custom attributes and the solution proposed by @peterjmag is the correct one.

Comment: @KevinFarrugia data attrubutes are still custom attributes, and adding attributes to a DOM via `element.setAttribute('custom-attribute', 'some value');` isn't JSX at all.

Answer (score 29):

Consider you want to pass a custom attribute named `myAttr` with value `myValue`, this will work:

```
<MyComponent data-myAttr={myValue} />
```

Comment: @GusDeCool First of all it is stated that was tested with react `15.3.1`, so your downvote does not make any sense since you are complaining that it does not work with `15.5.4`. Second, I have just test it with `^15.6.1` and it works just fine. Double check your code.

Comment: ah i see, it was on `react-dom` not `react`. sorry, my bad :).

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can add custom attributes by prepending them with either `data-` or `aria-`. See also: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html

Comment: **react 16 and on**

Comment: This feels like the most HTML5 compliant answer

Comment: @MorrisS This is not correct, because it actually works since react 15.6.x.

Answer (score 14):

if you are using es6 this should work:

```
<input {...{ "customattribute": "somevalue" }} />
```

Comment: Your genius! Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the "**is**" attribute to disable the React attribute whitelist for an element.

See my anwser here:
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21648347/true-custom-attributes-e-g-microdata-in-react/33860892#33860892)

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this problem a lot when attempting to use SVG with react.

I ended up using quite a dirty fix, but it's useful to know this option existed. Below I allow the use of the `vector-effect` attribute on SVG elements.

```
import SVGDOMPropertyConfig from 'react/lib/SVGDOMPropertyConfig.js';
import DOMProperty from 'react/lib/DOMProperty.js';

SVGDOMPropertyConfig.Properties.vectorEffect = DOMProperty.injection.MUST_USE_ATTRIBUTE;
SVGDOMPropertyConfig.DOMAttributeNames.vectorEffect = 'vector-effect';
```

As long as this is included/imported before you start using react, it should work.

Comment: interesting. I'll check it out

Answer (score 3):

See attribute value in console on click event

```
//...
   alertMessage (cEvent){
           console.log(cEvent.target.getAttribute('customEvent')); /*display attribute value */
        }
//...
```

simple add **customAttribute** as your wish in render method

```
render(){
    return <div>
//..
    <button customAttribute="My Custom Event Message" onClick={this.alertMessage.bind(this) } >Click Me</button>
            </div>
        }
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what version of React you are using, you may need to use something like this. I know Facebook is thinking about deprecating string refs in the somewhat near future.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.test).setAttribute('custom-attribute', 'some value');
    },
    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <span ref={(ref) => this.test = ref}>Element with a custom attribute</span>
        </div>;
    }
});

React.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[Facebook's ref documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html)

Answer (score 2):

uniqueId is custom attribute.

```
<a {...{ "uniqueId": `${item.File.UniqueId}` }}  href={item.File.ServerRelativeUrl} target='_blank'>{item.File.Name}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what exactly is preventing you from doing this, there's another option that requires no changes to your current implementation. You should be able to [augment React](https://github.com/jedmao/react-bem/blob/master/src/augmentReact.ts) in your project with a `.ts` or `.d.ts` file (not sure which) at project root. It would look something like this:

```
declare module 'react' {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends React.DOMAttributes<T> {
        'custom-attribute'?: string; // or 'some-value' | 'another-value'
    }
}
```

Another possibility is the following:

```
declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        [elemName: string]: any;
    }
}
```

See [JSX | Type Checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#type-checking)

You might even have to wrap that in a `declare global {`. I haven't landed on a final solution yet.

See also: [How do I add attributes to existing HTML elements in TypeScript/JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093655/how-do-i-add-attributes-to-existing-html-elements-in-typescript-jsx)

Answer (score 1):

For any custom attributes I use react-any-attr package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-any-attr