# How to change reactid suffix in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to change `data-reactid` attributes to my custom attributes like `data-hello="world"` in react?

```
<a data-reactid="......" ></a>
```

Comment: Please show us your effort. What have you done so far.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? http://stackoverflow.com/q/31273093/74230

Comment: there is literally no reason to use data attributes in react. Whatever you're trying to achieve should be done other ways.

Comment: @BlairAnderson: `data-` attribs are great for hitting with CSS no matter the framework that makes the html

Comment: @dandavis that is what classes are for? they are also framework agnostic.

Comment: @BlairAnderson: classes can be a lot harder to use when you're not hitting a "flag"-shaped value, like `[data-day=6]` or `[data-url$=.org]`... they are also used extensively by CSS frameworks like bootstrap and media embeds. I appreciate that _props_ should store "config", but with react's "hands-off" DOM restrictions, smarter CSS is more important than ever and can reduce JSX cruft.

Comment: @dandavis yeah I think instead of using CSS to check `[data-url$=.org]` i would prefer to add classes or inline-styles in react. this video(https://youtu.be/RBg2_uQE4KM) was really enlightening to see how react will be able to help us eliminate excess css/styles in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Update: As of React 15, data-reactid has been removed and is never written to the DOM as an attribute*

The short answer: Don't touch the data-reactid. Ever. It is a vital part of React, and basically used to perform the correct DOM manipulations when the virtual DOM tree is changed. Pretend it's not there.

However, you can add your own data- attributes in any way you wish:

```
render () {
    return (
        <h1 data-hello={this.props.hello}>{this.props.title}</h1>
    );
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/0or98zjx/

Comment: In your code still i can see <h1 data-hello="World" data-reactid=".0">A Title</h1>

Comment: Of course, React injects data-reactid, as I said, because it is what React hooks into when the DOM changes. Just exactly what are you trying to do? If you want to manipulate data-reactid, you can pass `key="myId"` to the component. the output will be `<h1 data-reactid=".0.$myId">`, but this is only necessary when iterating an array or something similar. See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0or98zjx/2/

Answer (score 0):

React creates the virtual DOM a, it measures the difference between the actual DOM and and virtual DOM if there is any change it will change the virtual DOM. So react.id will be a part of virtual DOM .