# How do I add attributes to existing HTML elements in TypeScript/JSX?

Tags: typescript, jsx

Anyone know how to properly add/extend all native HTML element attributes with custom ones?

With [the TypeScript documentation for merging interfaces](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces), I thought that I could just do this:

```
interface HTMLElement {
    block?: BEM.Block;
    element?: BEM.Element;
    modifiers?: BEM.Modifiers;
}

<div block="foo" />; // error
```

But I get the following Intellisense error in vscode 1.6.1 (latest):

> [ts] Property 'block' does not exist on type 'HTMLProps'.

The `HTMLProps` to which they are referring is `React.HTMLProps<T>` and the `div` element is declared to use it like so:

```
namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        div: React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>
    }
}
```

I tried redeclaring the `div`, but to no avail.

Related: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11684

**Edit:** Here's what ended up working for me:

```
declare module 'react' {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
        block?: string
        element?: string
        modifiers?: Modifiers // <-- custom interface
    }
}
```

Comment: @MadaraUchiha What about `extend`ing `React.HTMLProps<T>`? Or even merging declarations with `React.HTMLProps<T>`?

Comment: @ZevSpitz I've tried both and they didn't work well. Extending doesn't help, because I can't force it to use my interface, it'll just use `React.HTMLProps<T>`, and merging declarations simply didn't work, it completely ignored them. If you can make a case where it does work, consider posting it as an answer.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha _merging the declarations simply didn't work_ I presume you mean `namespace React { interface HTMLProps<T> { /*custom elements here*/ } }`? I don't know what the `HTMLProps` declaration looks like, it may be necessary to match it.

Comment: I have a question: why is this needed? Is there a problem with using `data-*` properties?

Comment: can you create playground, codepen or jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like in older versions of type definition files (v0.14) the interfaces were simply declared under a global React namespace, so previously you could use the standard merging syntax.

```
declare namespace React {

    interface HTMLProps<T> extends HTMLAttributes, ClassAttributes<T> {
    }
}
```

However the new version of d.ts file (v15.0) have declared everything inside a module. Since modules do not support merging, to the best of my knowledge the only option right now seems to be `module augmentation`:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

I did the following experiment and it worked for me:

```
import * as React from 'react';

declare module 'react' {
     interface HTMLProps<T> {
        block?:string;
        element?:string;
        modifiers?:string;
    }

}

export const Foo = () => {

    return (
        <div block="123" element="456">
        </div>
    )
};
```

Obviously this is quite tedious, you could put the augmentation code in another file as shown in the example from the typescript handbook, and import it:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './react_augmented';
```

But it's still quite dirty. So maybe it's best to address the issue with the contributors of the type definition file.

Comment: Thank you! We solved the problem in another way in the meantime, but this is a detailed answer with everything needed to solve the question as it was asked. You have my +1 and the bounty. Good job! :)

Comment: @Madara'sGhost can you share the other way you solved this?

Comment: @nishanths I cannot, since I do not even remember in what context I had this particular problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to use glamor's [createElement](https://github.com/threepointone/glamor/blob/master/docs/createElement.md) replacement which adds a `css` prop to every element.

To add to the accepted answer, module augmentation seems to do the trick but `HTMLProps` only worked for non-input elements. The correct interfaces to extend seems to be `HTMLAttributes` and `SVGAttributes`.

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    css?: any
  }

  interface SVGAttributes<T> {
    css?: any
  }
}
```

To avoid importing the module augmentation in every component, re-export  createElement:

```
// createElement.ts
import { createElement } from 'glamor/react'

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
    css?: any
  }

  interface SVGAttributes<T> {
    css?: any
  }
}

export default createElement
```

Then tell TS to use our `createElement` for JSX with this tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "jsxFactory": "createElement"
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
// MyComponent.tsx
import createElement from './createElement'

export default function MyComponent() {
  return <div css={{ color: 'red' }} />
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Vue 3 with TSX

```js
// src/index.d.ts

import * as vue from 'vue';
declare module 'vue' {
  interface HTMLAttributes {
    className?: string;
    vHtml?: string;
    frameBorder?: string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An up-to-date example (May 2019)

React type definition file (by default - `index.d.ts` when staring with `create-react-app`) contain list of all the standard HTML elements, as well as known attributes.

In order to allow custom HTML attributes, you need to define it's typing.
Do that by expanding `HTMLAttributes` interface:

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    // extends React's HTMLAttributes
    custom?: string;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding non-standard attributes from [React TypeScript Cheatsheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/advanced/types_react_api#adding-non-standard-attributes)

```
// react-unstable-attributes.d.ts
import "react";

declare module "react" {
  interface ImgHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
    loading?: "auto" | "eager" | "lazy";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For vue, the following works:

```
declare module 'vue-tsx-support/types/dom' {
    interface InputHTMLAttributes  {
        autocorrect: string;
        autocapitalize
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any vaild example by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add module global for Vue 3 *.vue files to work and explicitly add react types in package.json devDependencies as such "@types/react": "^18.0.14".

```
// src/html.d.ts

declare global {
  declare module '@types/react' {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
      dataCy?: string;
      class?: string | string[] | Record<string, boolean> | Record<string, boolean>[];
    }
  }
}
```