# Property does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLDivElement>' with React 16

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Since React 16 now allows [custom DOM attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html), I tried to leverage this in my Typescript code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

<div className="page" size="A4">
</div>
```

but receive this error message:

> error TS2339: Property 'size' does not exist on type
>      'DetailedHTMLProps< HTMLAttributes< HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093655/how-do-i-add-attributes-to-existing-html-elements-in-typescript-jsx) suggests to do a `module augmentation`, so I tried this way:

```
import * as React from 'react';

declare module 'react' {
     interface HTMLProps<T> {
        size?:string;
    }    
}
```

Same error message.

Finally, I also tried to declare `page` as a new HTML tag:

```
declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      page: any
    }
  }
}

<page className="page" size="A4">
</page>
```

It gets rid of the error message, but the `size` attribute is completely ignored in the compiled code, and I end up with:

```
<page className="page">
</page>
```

Ideally, the last one is my preferred solution. I'd like to use the `size` custom attribute alongside the `page` custom tag.

> tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about TypeScript but for an idea -might be stupid-, how about trying `data-size`?

Comment: Wow... It got rid of my error, and compiled! What made you think of this and why does this work as opposed to any "non dash" name such as size? Could you write that as an answer so I can validate?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

HTML supports data-* attribute type for custom attributes. You can read about it more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp).

> **Definition and Usage** The data-* attributes is used to store custom
>   data private to the page or application.
>
> The data-* attributes gives us the ability to embed custom data
>   attributes on all HTML elements.
>
> The stored (custom) data can then be used in the page's JavaScript to
>   create a more engaging user experience (without any Ajax calls or
>   server-side database queries).
>
> The data-* attributes consist of two parts:
>
> - The attribute name should not contain any uppercase letters, and must
>     be at least one character long after the prefix "data-"
> - The attribute value can be any string
>
> **Note:** Custom attributes prefixed with "data-" will be completely ignored by the user agent.

Rather than just using `size="A4"` you can use `data-size="A4"`

**Example**

```
<div className="page" data-size="A4">
  // ....
</div>
```

Comment: It works but I am not sure this is the complete explanation: I tried page-size instead of data-size and it also works. Any name I try with a '-' in it seems to work, as if Typescript ignored the warning and forced the compilation. Thanks!

Comment: Like I said I don't know much about TypeScript. Might have a better explanation. thank you for the upvote though

Answer (score 23):

React type definition file (by default - `index.d.ts` when staring with `create-react-app`) contain list of all the standard HTML elements, as well as known attributes.

In order to allow custom HTML attributes, you need to define it's typing.
Do that by expanding `HTMLAttributes` interface:

```
declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    // extends React's HTMLAttributes
    custom?: string;
  }
}
```

Possibly related question:

[How do I add attributes to existing HTML elements in TypeScript/JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093655/how-do-i-add-attributes-to-existing-html-elements-in-typescript-jsx/56109822#56109822)

Comment: I tried importing AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes but got `Circular definition of import alias 'AriaAttributes'`, same error for the other import

Comment: After 3 hours this is the closest answer that did work

```typescript
declare module "react" {
  namespace JSX {
    interface HTMLTemplateElement extends HTMLElement {
      shadowroot?: "open" | "closed"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using styled-components, you can do it even simplier:

```
const App = props => {
  return <StyledDiv version={2.0}>My custom div</StyledDiv>
}

type Custom = {
  version?: number
}

const StyledDiv = styled.div<Custom>`
  // styles
`
```

Answer (score 7):

Not entirely related, but say you want to accept extra attributes in your custom component, using the spread operator like `...rest`. Here´s how you do it:

```
interface Props{
  icon?: string; 
}

type Button = Props & React.HTMLProps<HTMLButtonElement> & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>;

function Button({ 
  icon,
  ...rest
}: Button) {
  return (
    <button 
      {...rest}
    >
     {icon && <span>{icon}</span>}
     {children}       
    </button>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Size is a standard HTML attribute and is defined as number collision can be avoided with

```
<page $size="A4">
//...
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

you want create custom attributes in TSX react typescript? here you go

```
export function Spinner(props: { content?: JSX.Element } & React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>) {
  return <div className="sp sp-circle" {...props}></div>;
}
```