# How to add custom attribute in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This does not work for me:
[Property does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLDivElement>' with React 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215614/property-does-not-exist-on-type-detailedhtmlprops-htmldivelement-with-react)

I do not have index.d.ts by default, I created one but it did not help so I put it in a component folder and ts started to complain 'useState does not export from React'.

I am new in typescript.
I need something like this:

```
<div customAtribute="foo"/>bar</div>
```

Comment: You need to study the basics of JavaScript, TypeScript, and React preferably in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it works... thanks to everyone :)

```
declare namespace React {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends DOMAttributes<T> {
        customAttribute?: string;
    }
}
```