# How do I get the TypeScript engine to allow custom HTML attributes in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I presume the TypeScript engine within [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) has received an update that is now complaining for the first time that my pre-existing custom props on HTML elements are invalid. This is on a Babel/React/JSX project with no TypeScript whatsoever.

```
<div custom="bar" />
```

*Note: they are (technically) invalid, but I consume them, so I know what I'm doing (it's intentional).*

## [See it on CodePen!](https://codepen.io/jedmao/pen/yvPgPg/?editors=0010)

### See also

- [How do I add attributes to existing HTML elements in TypeScript/JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093655/how-do-i-add-attributes-to-existing-html-elements-in-typescript-jsx) (posted by myself over a year ago and doesn't work any more).
- [JSX | Type Checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#type-checking)

Comment: Can you use `data-` attributes, for example `data-custom` that should be valid

Comment: Provide error message please

Answer (score 11):

React type definition file (by default - `index.d.ts` when staring with `create-react-app`) contain list of all the standard HTML elements, as well as known attributes.

In order to allow custom HTML attributes, you need to define it's typing.
Do that by expanding `HTMLAttributes` interface:

```
import { HTMLAttributes } from "react";

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    // extends React's HTMLAttributes
    custom?: string;
  }
}
```

Read more about [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) on TypeScript docs.

Comment: This breaks typescript type checking for the 'react' module.

Comment: Don't forget to import `HTMLAttributes`

Answer (score 10):

> Note: If an attribute name is not a valid JS identifier (like a data-* attribute), it is not considered to be an error if it is not found in the element attributes type.

`<div data-custom="bar" />`

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#attribute-type-checking
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

Comment: add details to the answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: The answer was hyphens... all along? True heroes don't always wear capes! :)

Answer (score 2):

Project structure:

```sh
☁  extends-react-types  tree -I 'node_modules' 
.
├── App.tsx
├── index.d.ts
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── tsconfig.json

0 directories, 5 files
```

package version:

```json
{
  "name": "extends-react-types",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.56",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "dom"
        ],
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "jsx": "preserve",
    }
}
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

interface HomeProps extends React.ComponentPropsWithRef<'div'> {}
export default function Home(props: HomeProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p _name="name" _error={true}>
        123
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As you can see, there are two custom HTML attributes in `p` element: `_name` and `_error`. Now, we need to extend `HTMLAttributes` interface of `React` with these two custom HTML attributes.

**Option 1:**

`index.d.ts`:

```
import 'react';

declare module 'react' {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    _name?: string;
    _error?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Option 2:**

```
declare namespace React {
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends AriaAttributes, DOMAttributes<T> {
    _name?: string;
    _error?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]