# How to add extra props to a <button> in ReactJS with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a custom component that has a normal `<button>` tag and I'm adding a new prop to it called aria-current.

The problem is that Typescript complains that this property does not exist inside `<button>`(and it doesnt). My question is: How to add this property to a simple `<button>` tag?

[image]

Comment: you could wrap it into a customized <Button/> you create. and then you add whatever props you wish !!

Comment: well still he will encounter the same problem because the base button cant get it.  @oubaydos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
This property does exist on button, but you provide incorrect type. You need to specify the correct type and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Hi before I could help can you add the reason why you want to add a props to button
if the button tag dont get it's mean that he will never understand it and can't use it

**UPDATE:**

note that you can update but it will break the rest of the code
you can look on this thread

[How do I get the TypeScript engine to allow custom HTML attributes in JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48818162/how-do-i-get-the-typescript-engine-to-allow-custom-html-attributes-in-jsx)

or this

[How do I add attributes to existing HTML elements in TypeScript/JSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40093655/how-do-i-add-attributes-to-existing-html-elements-in-typescript-jsx)