# How TypeScript handles `data-*` attributes in JSX?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, custom-data-attribute

Consider this:

```
import type { JSX } from 'react';

const MyComponent = (): JSX.Element => (
  <div data-attr="bar">Foo</div>
);
```

This does not give any TypeScript error which is expected, however, I cannot find types for `data-*` custom attributes, something like

```
interface *** {
  // other attributes...
  `data-${string}`: string
}
```

Can anyone please tell me where in `d.ts` files are defining this?

Comment: does that helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285856/how-do-i-dynamically-set-html5-data-attributes-using-react

Comment: @TheTisiboth - How do the answers to that question answer this question?

Comment: Apparently is part of Typescript specification for JSX, as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50961972/3797799 (referring to the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#attribute-type-checking)). From my test, any prop with a `-` is considered valid by Typescript, ie. `<div what-is-this="hello" >asd</div>`.

Comment: Relevant quote from those docs: *"Note: If an attribute name is not a valid JS identifier (like a `data-*` attribute), it is not considered to be an error if it is not found in the element attributes type."*

Comment: @colinD - I think that qualifies as an answer to this question, and the linked question's answers don't, quite. Good find! I suggest you post it. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, yes, I was thinking it was a duplicate but the question is not the same. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of Typescript specification for JSX, as per the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#attribute-type-checking):

> Note: If an attribute name is not a valid JS identifier (like a data-* attribute), it is not considered to be an error if it is not found in the element attributes type.

It also extends to any property with a dash `-` inside, for example this is valid JSX for Typescript:

```
<div a-custom-attribute="hello"></div>
```