# How to fix "Warning: Unknown props `change-background`, `colorcode` on <div> tag. Remove these props from the element" error?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, reactjs

I'm having problems with loading a page that has been packed with Webpack. Im using React to render the page HTML. When I open my html in my web browser, it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: Unknown props `change-background`, `colorcode` on <div> tag. Remove these props from the element.
    in div (created by Component)
    in div (created by Component)
    in Component"
```

My html is:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssWEB.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bungee+Hairline" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-app="App">
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="public/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Element, scroller} from 'react-scroll';


const Component = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
        scroller.scrollTo('myScroller', {
            duration: 1500,
            delay: 500,
            smooth: true
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
              <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="style.less" type="text/css" />
              <script src="http://lesscss.googlecode.com/files/less-1.0.21.min.js"></script>
              <link type="text/javascript" href="jscode.js"></link>


              <header>
                La Barriada
              </header>


              <div className="cube" change-background colorcode="#f45642" ref={(el) => { this.messagesEnd = el; }}>
                <div className="front"><span>Experience</span></div>
                <div className="back"></div>
                <div className="top"></div>
                <div className="bottom"></div>
                <div className="left"></div>
                <div className="right"></div>
              </div>

              <div className="wrap2">
                <div className="cube" change-background>
                  <div className="front" colorcode="#f45642"><span>Work</span></div>
                  <div className="back"></div>
                  <div className="top"></div>
                  <div className="bottom"></div>
                  <div className="left"></div>
                  <div className="right"></div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div className="wrap3">
                <div className="cube" change-background>
                  <div className="front" colorcode="#f45642"><span>Contact</span></div>
                  <div className="back"></div>
                  <div className="top"></div>
                  <div className="bottom"></div>
                  <div className="left"></div>
                  <div className="right"></div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <Element name="link1">
                <div className="bg2" id="linkhere"></div>
              </Element>

              <div className="slide1">
              </div>

              <div className="slidechild1">
              <div className="centerbox">
              <div className="center">
                <ul>
                  <li data-ng-click="clicked2()" id="B1">aa</li>
                  <li id="B2">cc.i</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to double check if those attributes are sorted by React.  You can do so by reading the [docs page here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes).

It doesn't look like those DOM attributes  `change-background` or  `colorcode` are
 supported.

---

**EDIT:** The same docs state that:

> *In React, all DOM properties and attributes (including event handlers)
>   should be camelCased. For example, the HTML
>   attribute tabindex corresponds to the attribute tabIndex in React.*

So it might be worth trying `changeBackground` and `colorCode` respectively in your JSX and see if that does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

ReactJS currently don't supports custom attributes as specified [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html). It strips of unknown attributes. You can solve the problem by manually adding the attribute in the `componentDidMount` method as specified in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273093/how-to-add-custom-html-attributes-in-jsx).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use any custom attributes as a prop. Rather you should use valid html attributes. React supports almost every valid html attributes. [Here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#all-supported-html-attributes) is the list of valid html attributes supported by React.