# Generating id's for React components for Selenium tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, react-redux

I'd like to generate `id`'s for almost every element in my website, to have an easier time handling elements for Selenium tests. Is this a good approach? My application changes quite a bit.

I can't seem to add the `id` HTML attribute to the React component, because React interprets it as props e.g.

```
<NewEl id='test'/>
```

... and `NewEl` gets `id` props instead of attribute. Sometimes I can't access the React component because I use third party components.

How should I change that `id` attribute? Is my approach a good solution?

Comment: How can this be related to `Selenium` ? Am I missing something?

Comment: Check this to pass custom attributes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273093/how-to-add-custom-html-attributes-in-jsx