# How to embed a YouTube iframe using React + Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, youtube

Typescript seems to be working against me here. Here's what I want to embed:

```
<iframe 
    width="560" 
    height="315" 
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/BLAH?showinfo=0" 
    frameBorder="0" 
    allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
    allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

The problem is the `allow` attribute:

```
TS2339: Property 'allow' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<IframeHTMLAttributes<HTMLIFrameElement>, HTMLIFrameElement>'.
```

...which is true, it's not in index.d.ts. How can I forcibly add this attribute, or somehow cast `iframe` to any any type, etc?

Comment: If moving to react 16 is not an option - there's still a trick to make it work - check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273093/how-to-add-custom-html-attributes-in-jsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to change the attribute from `allow` to `data-allow`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me using React 17.0.1 in gatsby 3.0.1:

create an index.d.ts file in your project. Include this code:

```
import "react";
    
declare module 'react' {
   export interface IframeHTMLAttributes<T> {
          controls?: 0 | 1
          fs?: 0 | 1
          hl?: string
        }
    }
```

Just an example - all available props can be seen in the Youtube Iframe doc:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#origin

point to the index-file in the tsconfig.json-file:

```
"include": ["src/types/global.d.ts" ]
```

That's it!