# Custom attribute in script tag using ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to add this `<script>` tag to my React code:

```
<script
    src="mySource"
    sp-form-id="LongString"
  />
```

but when I check the elements the `sp-form-id` attribute is not there:

[image]

And it shows me this error:

```
index.js:2177 Warning: Unknown prop `sp-form-id` on <script> tag. Remove this prop from the element.
```

But, as fas as I know, with React 16 this wouldn't be an issue, it should still add the custom prop.

How do I add that attribute to the `<script>` tag?

Comment: This should work just fine. Are you sure you're using v16? (You can render `{React.version}` somewhere to check)

Comment: oh whoops, I wasn't using React 16.. changed it, now it works. But, how would I do this in React 15?

Comment: Never had to do this myself, but there's a couple of suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273093

Comment: Perfect, thanks mate!