# Custom HTML attributes on React component

Tags: html, reactjs, babeljs

I'm trying to add a custom HTML attribute on a React component:

```
const Parent = () => (
    <div className="parent">
      <Child data-custom="foo" />
    </div>
);
```

Where Child is another React component, but the attribute gets stripped on the output HTML. I'm aware that I could simply add the attribute on the Child root element, like so:

```
 const Child = () => <div className="child" data-custom="foo" />
```

Or read the attribute in the Child component via props, but that's not what i'm looking since that would couple the attribute with the component, and I'm looking for a more contextual approach (the attribute would be used for test automation purposes).

Is there a clean way to do that in React?

I'm also considering writing a Babel plugin to add the attribute or prevent the stripping, but that would be another question.

Thanks!

Comment: [dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273093/how-to-add-custom-html-attributes-in-jsx)

Comment: @Ardit Related but necessarily a dupe because the case is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React element doesn't necessarily correspond to DOM element that could have HTML attributes. React component can be rendered to multiple DOM elements or no elements at all.

If `Child` should be able to provide additional props or attributes to child DOM element, it should pass them explicitly:

```
const Child = props => <div className="child" {...props} />
```

This way `data-custom="foo"` will be passed to `<div>`.

Comment: I'm very new to React, wasn't aware that React components could be rendered to no DOM elements. This solution works! Thanks! I'll stick to it, although i was trying to avoid explicitly managing props inside each component. Maybe a hook or a babel plugin?

Comment: I'm not aware of any helper, and this would be tricky because it needs to hook into React renderer to do this. And still, it's unclear how it should work if a component returns not DOM element but something else. E.g. `Child` returns `Fragment` with multiple children. Should it discard data attribute or give it to all children? FWIW, there's a convention over `data-testid` attribute that is used by react-testing-library, see https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#bytestid . The attribute is supposed to be set manually on significant elements.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can try this in your react script.

```html
const MyCompo = () => {
 return (
  <div>
   <p>HTML Code</p>
  </div>
 );
}
export default About;
```

Otherwise you can create class and then define your components and then export them.

```html
import React from 'react';

import '../assets/css/style.css';
import '../assets/css/pure-min.css';
import '../assets/css/custom.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';

class FirstScreen extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.handleLoad = this.handleLoad.bind(this);
 }
 componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('load', this.handleLoad);
 }
 handleLoad() {
  
  }

 render() {
  return <div>HTML Code</div>;
 }
}

export default FirstScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below syntax

```
const Parent = () => (
    <div className="parent">
      <Child data-custom="foo"/>
    </div>
);
```

```
const Child = ({...props}) => (<div className="child" {...props} />)
```