# Custom React Attributes with Brackets

Tags: reactjs, google-amp, amp-bind

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33860892/1102215) it's explained how to use the undocumented `is` feature to add a custom attribute to a React element. However, I'd like to add an attribute for use with [amp-bind](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-bind/) which is surrounded by brackets. When I try this the attribute is not added:

```
const ampProps = {
  '[class]': 'foo.bar',
};

return <div is {...ampProps}><MyComponent></div>
```

How can I add the custom attribute?

Comment: const ampProps = class => ({
  [class]: 'foo.bar',
});

return <div is {...ampProps(class)}><MyComponent></div>

Comment: the point is to have the brackets in the prop. your proposed solution doesn't do that

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-amp/pages/_document.js

Comment: There are only two options - or you will have brackets like in your sample - inside of a string - or you will not have brackets, since [something] will be converted to something value.

Comment: For AMP bind with react you can use its alternate syntax mentioned in official doc of amp-bind.

https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/#bindings

Answer (score 3):

For AMP bind with react you can use its alternate syntax mentioned in official doc of [amp-bind](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/#bindings).

> An alternative, XML-compatible syntax can also be used in the form of **data-amp-bind-property**

Example `You can write [text] binding as data-amp-bind-text` which will not give error in React.

Comment: data-amp-bind-src does not seem to work with an amp-list

Answer (score 1):

You may need to setup React to accept many of the AMP directives using ReactInjection.

After you do it, the HTML produced by React will contain it.

```
import { DOMProperty } from 'react-dom/lib/ReactInjection'
DOMProperty.injectDOMPropertyConfig({
    Properties: {
        '[class]': DOMProperty.MUST_USE_PROPERTY
    }
})
```

---

UPDATE (AUG-25-2017):

The code above solves the case for regular HTML tags like div, ul, span, etc.

I'm currently having an issue placing **[src]** attribute inside a custom **amp-list**. React code does not take injected DOM Property into account for custom tags, the code considers that an attribute starting with '[' is not "safe" and remove it from the 'amp-list', regardless of the setup of injectDOMPropertyConfig.

There is a RFC for React 16 that would solve the issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10399

I have also placed a question on:
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/10385

---

Comment: Hi @PedroIsrael, that was some time again now, but did you ever figure out the issue with [src]? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the alternative syntax

```
<tag data-amp-bind-x="foo">
```

instead of

```
<tag [x]="foo">
```